# How do I check if precompiled headers are really used?

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, precompiled-headers, pch

As such possibility is stated in gcc documentation https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html I have folder with precompilded headers, name it all.h.gch. It contains several precompiled headers like all1.h.gch, all2.h.gch, etc, each compiled for different set of defines. I build them with separate makefile each.

After that, I build my project, name it test, with its own makefile. I specify pch folder with `-I` option: `-I/path/to/all.h.gch`

According to link above, compiler should automatically pick suitable header from `all.h.gch` folder.

How do I check if it really uses precompiled header instead of compile all.h each time anew? Measuring compile time using 'time' utility is not an option, because compile time is too small to notice difference.

Comment: Are you looking for the [`-fpch-preprocess`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-fpch-preprocess) option?

Comment: @Eljay That's because now I test it on stub project. When I figure how to make it work, I will use it in real project. On Windows it does reduce compile time, now I want it on Linux too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use [`-H`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-H) option to manually check which header is used. Emphasis mine:

> -H
>
> Print the name of each header file used, in addition to other normal activities. Each name is indented to show how deep in the ‘#include’ stack it is. **Precompiled header files are also printed, even if they are found to be invalid; an invalid precompiled header file is printed with ‘...x’ and a valid one with ‘...!’**.

Answer (score 2):

Not what you asked for, but I wouldn't rely on `#include` picking up PCHs, because Clang doesn't do this (and it's a good idea to have a build process compatible with both GCC and Clang).

Instead, include the PCH header via a flag: `-include path/to/header.h`.

To be certain that the PCH actually gets used (and to be able to switch between different versions of the PCH with different flags), you can put `header.h.gch` into a different directory (away from the original `header.h`), then only pass the path to `.gch` to `-include` (but without the `.gch` extension).

Comment: If I'm wrong, I'd appreciate some explanation (so I can fix *my* makefiles too).

Comment: Not my downvote, but one reason(as a reader) I think can be due to the phrase,  *"Not what you asked for,.."* might be the reason for the downvote. But that too doesn't seem like a good reason for downvote tbh.

Comment: @user12002570 I didn't have this phrase in the first version, and just jumped straight to the alternative solution, maybe that's why.